# ListPlot with many variables

Tags: plotting

If I have a function:

`f[x_, y_, z_, d_] = 4 x + y + z + d;`

and made lists for `f` for different values of the free parameters x,y,z,d, by

`T := Table[f[x, y, z, d], {x, 2, 5, 1}, {y, 2, 6, 2}, {z, 5, 10, 1}, {d, 3, 7, 1}]`

How to plot `f[x, y, z, d]` versus any coulomb of the table, i.e., x, y, z or d ..

** Edit **

So why ListPlot dosn't work if I one more than two varibles change, i.e.,
 for

`T = Table[{x, If[-50 < DC[x, y] < 50, sigma[x, y, z, d]]}, {x, -5, -2,
     1}, {y, 2, 6, 1}, {z, 6, 9, 1}, {d, 2, 9, 1}];`

ListPlot[T] stuck ..

Comment: `Table[ { x, Table[ f[x, y, z, d] } ... ]`?

Comment: Just to explain @Kuba 's comment `datax = Table[ { x, Table[ f[x, y0, z0, d0] }, {x,2,5,1} ]` and you have to use specific value `y0,z0,d0` for `y,z,d`. Then use `ListPlot[datax]`. Since you have an analytical expression you can also use `Plot[f[x,y0,z0,d0],{x,2,5}]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot your stuff like so:

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot3D[Norm[{4 x + y + z + d}], 
{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
ContourStyle -> (Directive[Opacity[.3, #]] & /@ {Red, Green, Cyan}),
Contours -> {1, 2, 3}, MeshStyle -> None], {d, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please see my question, I edit ..

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

Below you will find two examples.

- Example No.1 shows how to process function using a set of lists as
  input parameters (per column basis).
- Example No.2 shows how to process function using all possible
  combinations of passed parameters; in your example it is `{x,y,z,d}`

**Example 1:**

```
(*data*)
x = {2, 5, 1};
y = {2, 6, 2};
z = {5, 10, 1};
d = {3, 7, 1};

(*operation*)
Thread[f[x, y, z, d]];
```

**Example 2:**

```
(*operation*)
Outer[f, x, y, z, d];
```

Comment: So, you want to plot a function of 4 independent variables in 3D space ? The only way seems to be by ListContourPlot3D