# Generate list of pairs for a function in many varibels

Tags: plotting

In my previous post

[ListPlot with many variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117882/listplot-with-many-variables)

I asked how to plot function `f[x, y, z, d]` versus `x` for varying `y,z,d`

I learnt to do something like:

`T = Table[{x, f[x, 3, 1, 2]}, {x, 2, 5, 1}]`, then

`ListPlot[T]`

Also I tried to vary one more variable, i.e.,

`T = Table[{x, f[x, y, 2, 2]}, {x, -5, -2, 1}, {y, 1, 4, 1}];`

Still ListPlot works fine, because `T` still generate list of pairs:
`{{{-5, -8}, {-5, -7}, {-5, -6}, {-5, -5}}...}`

On the other hand when I vary 3 or 4 variables, like

`T2 = Table[{x, sigma[x, y, z, 2]}, {x, -5, -2, 1}, {y, 1, 4, 1}, {z, 1,5, 2}, {d, 1, 5, 2}];`

ListPlot returns nothing, I think I should to use `Flatten[#,3]` here to generate list of pairs of {x, f} as in `T`, so that ListPlot can make the graph ?

Comment: This seems to me an exact duplicate of the question you asked earlier today: [ListPlot with many variables](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117882/27951). You received an answer to that previous question, so repeating your question unchanged is not useful. If the previous answer does not satisfy your requirements, then please explain why in that question. If you have a different problem, then modify your question to highlight the differences.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: What's the question here? As you say `Flatten[T, 3]` will give a list of pairs that you can `ListPlot`. Is there a problem with the result?

Comment: It is easy to experiment with Mathematica. If you think `Flatten` might work, try it and see what happens. The worst case outcome is that you will learn that you were wrong, which is still knowledge gained.

Comment: Ok .. I got it ..